Building open62541 Library in ThreadX NetX for OPC-UA Server on Renesas Embedded Device
I'm working on setting up an OPC-UA server on an embedded device using a Renesas microcontroller with Eclipse ThreadX as the real-time operating system (RTOS). My goal is to allow a client application, such as UaExpert running on a Windows 11 PC, to connect to this server.
I've chosen the open62541 library for implementing the OPC-UA server functionality. However, I've encountered an issue with missing TCP/IP header files in ThreadX-NetX, which are required by open62541.
Has anyone encountered a similar setup or have experience integrating the open62541 library with ThreadX-NetX? I'd appreciate any insights or guidance on how to resolve this issue.
Thank you in advance for your help!
the way to configure the build options, include and so on.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
